# Very Strange View Behavior When Implementing 3D Touch Preview

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, 3dtouch

I'm running into a very strange issue with 3D Touch previewing in my app. As you press into a cell to show a preview, a view seems to grow out of the top left corner, until it's about to show the preview view controller, at which point it's the full size of the view controller.

[Here's a video of the behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxkbtBhsI7I)

I haven't been able to replicate in any apps I've created from scratch; however, creating a new tableview and view controller in the *same app* it still does it:

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iz0yEY4uMKA)

I know this isn't a lot to go on, but I've exhausted my debugging knowledge. I'm not getting auto layout errors, when I debug the view hierarchy the view just isn't there. I'm hoping someone has experienced this and knows how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Having the same problem with a UICollectionView with a segue in the storyboard. Not a UICollectionViewController. I have to imagine this is an Apple bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to hunt this bug down. Turns out it's caused (in my case) by https://github.com/icanzilb/EasyAnimation. When I remove the library the bug is gone.

Cheers!

Edit: As it happens it's documented here: https://github.com/icanzilb/EasyAnimation/issues/14

Comment: There it is! They always say you risk breaking stuff with third party libraries, but this is the first time I've experienced it. Thanks!